# Facebook Games on My Web Page

Tags: facebook, youtube, facebook-application

Is there a way to set any facebook game or application to my web page. Think like youtube videos. There is a link a simply we can set it to our blog or web page.

Answer (score 1):

No. They require Facebook's platform to function.

Comment: Why it cant be possible? using facebook and facebook login and its the properties of these applications would be nice.if they can be reachable fromother sites.

Comment: Probably because Facebook wants to keep users on *their* site. Not yours.